# Impossible to load fixtures in Symfony2 "Could not find any fixtures to load"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, osx-mountain-lion, fixtures

I desperately try to load Doctrine fixtures into my DB.
When I call the global cli load function, nothing looks bad at the beginning:

```
> purging database
> loading [1] namespace_of_my_first_fixture_file
> loading [2] namespace_of_my_second_fixture_file
...
```

But it fails in the middle of the process when it tries to re-use an object from a previous loaded fixtures (wrong index):

```
[ErrorException]                                                                                                                                                          
Notice: Undefined index: my_object_index in /Users/Swop/project/vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/ReferenceRepository.php line 145
```

I look at the DB and nothing is inserted, in any tables. If I try to load only the first fixture (which seems to be loaded according to the above paste), I've got an error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                          
Could not find any fixtures to load in:                             

- src/MyOrg/MyBundleBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/MyFirstFixtureFileData.php
```

By the way, I just run that on my MacOS X (Mountain Lion) with a self-compiled PHP 5.4 instance.

The fixtures data loading works well on my Linux box.

Answer (score 4):

I could not find a good example in the docs and finally found that this works.  Just use the folder location and do not specify the fixture file.

```
doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=src/MyOrg/MyBundleBundle/DataFixtures/ORM --append
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [DoctrineFixturesBundle documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#sharing-objects-between-fixtures).

Your data fixture classes need to implement `OrderedFixtureInterface` so they are loaded in a pre-set order.

You can then setup references with `$this->addReference('ref-name', $variable)` and refer to those references in another fixture with `$this->getReference('ref-name')`.

My guess as to why it seemed to work on your linux box is because the fixures were loaded in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

Just run into this aswell. My fixtures where working on my local windows environment, but failed in my linux production environment.

My problem was case sensitivity (as it is so often in windows-linux).

I named the data fixtures directory

```
Datafixtures
```

While the script looks for

```
DataFixtures
```

> Spot the capital F in the second directory name, I didnt ;-)

I hope this saves someones time.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when upgrading doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle

This helped me out:

> The automatic loading of fixtures in a directory (e.g.
>   AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM) was removed. Instead, register your
>   fixture classes as services and tag then with doctrine.fixture.orm.

Source:https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/blob/master/UPGRADE.md